# Working on LWC component using Aura. Scan printer on local IP showing error

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, js

Working on LWC component using Aura.
Getting an issue when calling zebra print function to find printer on local network. (same code working on lightning component)

code is added in 'staticresource/module1'

[image]

```
** code is added in Module.js file as staticresource**
var $jscomp=$jscomp||{};$jscomp.scope={};$jscomp.checkStringArgs=function(b,h,c){if(null==b)throw new TypeError("The 'this' value for String.prototype."+c+" must not be null or undefined");if(h instanceof RegExp)throw new TypeError("First argument to String.prototype."+c+" must not be a regular expression");return b+""};$jscomp.ASSUME_ES5=!1;$jscomp.ASSUME_NO_NATIVE_MAP=!1;$jscomp.ASSUME_NO_NATIVE_SET=!1;
$jscomp.defineProperty=$jscomp.ASSUME_ES5||"function"==typeof Object.defineProperties?Object.defineProperty:function(b,h,c){b!=Array.prototype&&b!=Object.prototype&&(b[h]=c.value)};$jscomp.getGlobal=function(b){return"undefined"!=typeof window&&window===b?b:"undefined"!=typeof global&&null!=global?global:b};$jscomp.global=$jscomp.getGlobal(this);
$jscomp.polyfill=function(b,h,c,e){if(h){c=$jscomp.global;b=b.split(".");for(e=0;e<b.length-1;e++){var k=b[e];k in c||(c[k]={});c=c[k]}b=b[b.length-1];e=c[b];h=h(e);h!=e&&null!=h&&$jscomp.defineProperty(c,b,{configurable:!0,writable:!0,value:h})}};
$jscomp.polyfill("String.prototype.startsWith",function(b){return b?b:function(b,c){var e=$jscomp.checkStringArgs(this,b,"startsWith");b+="";var h=e.length,p=b.length;c=Math.max(0,Math.min(c|0,e.length));for(var l=0;l<p&&c<h;)if(e[c++]!=b[l++])return!1;return l>=p}},"es6","es3");
var BrowserPrint=function(){function b(a,b){var d=new XMLHttpRequest;"withCredentials"in d?d.open(a,b,!0):"undefined"!=typeof XDomainRequest?(d=new XDomainRequest,d.open(a,b)):d=null;return d}function h(a,b,d){void 0===b&&(b=e.defaultSuccessCallback);void 0===d&&(d=e.defaultErrorCallback);return c(a,b,d)}function c(a,b,d){a.onreadystatechange=function(){a.readyState===XMLHttpRequest.DONE&&200===a.status?""===a.responseType?b(a.responseText):b(a.response):a.readyState===XMLHttpRequest.DONE&&(d?d(a.response):
console.log("error occurred with no errorCallback set."))};return a}var e={},k={},p=/^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/7.0");var l="http://127.0.0.1:9100/";p&&"https:"===location.protocol&&(l="https://127.0.0.1:9101/");e.Device=function(a){var m=this;this.name=a.name;this.deviceType=a.deviceType;this.connection=a.connection;this.uid=a.uid;this.version=2;this.provider=a.provider;this.manufacturer=a.manufacturer;this.readRetries="bluetooth"===
this.connection?1:0;this.sendErrorCallback=function(d){};this.sendFinishedCallback=function(d){};this.readErrorCallback=function(d){};this.readFinishedCallback=function(d){};this.send=function(d,a,f){var g=b("POST",l+"write");g&&(void 0!==m&&(void 0===a&&(a=m.sendFinishedCallback),void 0===f&&(f=m.sendErrorCallback)),c(g,a,f),g.send(JSON.stringify({device:{name:this.name,uid:this.uid,connection:this.connection,deviceType:this.deviceType,version:this.version,provider:this.provider,manufacturer:this.manufacturer},
data:d})))};this.sendUrl=function(d,a,f,e){var g=b("POST",l+"write");g&&(c(m,g,a,f),d={device:{name:this.name,uid:this.uid,connection:this.connection,deviceType:this.deviceType,version:this.version,provider:this.provider,manufacturer:this.manufacturer},url:d},null!=e&&void 0!=e&&(d.options=e),g.send(JSON.stringify(d)))};this.sendFile=function(d,a,f){if("string"===typeof d)e.loadFileFromUrl(d,function(d){m.sendFile(d,a,f)},f);else{var g=b("POST",l+"write");if(g){g.responseType="text";h(g,a,f);var c=
new FormData,n={};n.device=m;c.append("json",JSON.stringify(n));c.append("blob",d);g.send(c)}}};this.convertAndSendFile=function(d,a,b,c){c||(c={});c.action||(c.action="print");e.convert(d,this,c,a,b)};this.read=function(d,a){var f=b("POST",l+"read");f&&(void 0!==m&&(void 0===d&&(d=m.readFinishedCallback),void 0===a&&(a=m.readErrorCallback)),c(f,d,a),f.send(JSON.stringify({device:{name:this.name,uid:this.uid,connection:this.connection,deviceType:this.deviceType,version:this.version,provider:this.provider,
manufacturer:this.manufacturer}})))};this.readUntilStringReceived=function(d,a,b,e,c){c||(c="");void 0===e&&(e=this.readRetries);a=function(a,b,e,f,g){return function(c){if(c&&0!==c.length)f=0;else if(0>=f){b(g);return}c=g+c;""!==d&&-1<c.indexOf(d)?b(c):a.readUntilStringReceived(d,b,e,f-1,c)}}(this,a,b,e,c);this.read(a,b)};this.readAllAvailable=function(a,b,f){this.readUntilStringReceived("",a,b,f)};this.sendThenRead=function(a,b,f){this.send(a,function(a){return function(){a.read(b,f)}}(this),f)};
this.sendThenReadUntilStringReceived=function(a,b,f,e,c){this.send(a,function(a){return function(){a.readUntilStringReceived(b,f,e,c)}}(this),e)};this.sendThenReadAllAvailable=function(a,b,e,c){this.send(a,function(a){return function(){a.readUntilStringReceived("",b,e,c)}}(this),e)}};e.defaultSuccessCallback=function(){};e.defaultErrorCallback=function(){};e.ApplicationConfiguration=function(){this.application={version:"1.2.0.3",build_number:3,api_level:2,platform:"",supportedConversions:{}}};e.getLocalDevices=
function(a,c,d){var g=b("GET",l+"available");g&&(window.finishedFunction=function(b){response=b;response=JSON.parse(response);for(var c in response)if(response.hasOwnProperty(c)&&response[c].constructor===Array)for(arr=response[c],b=0;b<arr.length;++b)arr[b]=new e.Device(arr[b]);void 0===d?a(response):(response.hasOwnProperty(d)||(response[d]=[]),a(response[d]))},h(g,window.finishedFunction,c),g.send())};e.getDefaultDevice=function(a,c,d){var g="default";void 0!==a&&null!=a&&(g=g+"?type="+a);if(a=b("GET",l+g))window.finishedFunction=
function(a){response=a;""===response?c(null):(response=JSON.parse(response),a=new e.Device(response),c(a))},a=h(a,window.finishedFunction,d),a.send()};e.getApplicationConfiguration=function(a,c){var d=b("GET",l+"config");d&&(window.finishedFunction=function(b){response=b;""===response?a(null):(response=JSON.parse(response),a(response))},h(d,window.finishedFunction,c),d.send())};e.readOnInterval=function(a,b,d){if(void 0===d||0===d)d=1;readFunc=function(){a.read(function(c){b(c);k[a]=setTimeout(readFunc,d)},function(b){k[a]=
setTimeout(readFunc,d)})};k[a]=setTimeout(readFunc,d)};e.stopReadOnInterval=function(a){k[a]&&clearTimeout(k[a])};e.bindFieldToReadData=function(a,b,d,c){e.readOnInterval(a,function(a){""!==a&&(b.value=a,void 0!==c&&null!=c&&c())},d)};e.loadFileFromUrl=function(a,c,d){request=b("get",a);console.log("ResponseType: "+request.responseType);request.responseType="blob";h(request,c,d);request.send()};e.convert=function(a,c,d,g,f){if(a)if("string"===typeof a)e.loadFileFromUrl(a,function(b){d.fromFormat||
(d.fromFormat=a.substring(a.length-3));e.convert(b,c,d,g,f)},f);else{var k=b("POST",l+"convert");a.type&&(a.type.startsWith("image/")||a.type.startsWith("application/"))&&(d.fromFormat=a.type.toLowerCase().replace("image/","").replace("application/","").replace("x-ms-",""));if(k){k.responseType="text";h(k,function(a){g(JSON.parse(a))},f);var m=new FormData,n={};null!=d&&void 0!==d&&(n.options=d);c&&(n.device=c);m.append("json",JSON.stringify(n));m.append("blob",a);k.send(m)}}else f?f("Resource not specified"):
e.defaultErrorCallback("Resource not specified")};return e}();
window.$jscomp = $jscomp;

// http://127.0.0.1:9100/ 
// https://127.0.0.1:9101

(function() {
      debugger;
      function sayHello() {
          console.log('hello from helloModule.js');
      }
      // this makes the sayHello function available in the window     namespace
      // so we can call window.sayHello from any LWC JS file
      window.sayHello = sayHello;



window.selected_device = null;
window.devices = []; 
window.ifZebraSuccess = false;
window.labelImageOnError = null; 

window.errorCallback = function(errorMessage) {
    ifZebraSuccess = false;
    if (document.getElementById('btnPrintLabel')) {
        document.getElementById('btnPrintLabel').style.display = 'inline';
    }

    if (document.getElementById('txtPrinterError')) {
        document.getElementById('txtPrinterError').style.display = 'block';
        if(labelImageOnError) {
            printImage(labelImageOnError);
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("PPplease configure your printer first. Please follow the link to download Installer : https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/printer-software/by-request-software.html#browser-print");
    }

    if(document.getElementById("selected_device")) {
        document.getElementById("selected_device").style.display = "none";
    }
};


//calling this method from 'component.js'

window.onPrintLabelClick = (labelType, labelImage, zplImage) => {
    console.log('onPrintLabelClick with param');
    labelImageOnError = labelImage;
    if (ifZebraSuccess === true && ifZplImage(labelType) == true && zplImage) {
        writeToSelectedPrinter(zplImage);
    } else if(labelImage){
        printImage(labelImage);
    }
};

 
window.ifZplImage = (labelType) => {
    return labelType && labelType.toUpperCase() === 'ZPL';
};

window.writeToSelectedPrinter = (dataToWrite) => {
    if(dataToWrite) {
        selected_device.send(dataToWrite, undefined, errorCallback);
    }
};       

window.printImage = (source) => {
    function imagetoPrint(source) {
        return "<html><head><script>function step1(){\n" +
            "setTimeout('step2()', 10);}\n" +
            "function step2(){window.print();window.close()}\n" +
            "</scri" + "pt></head><body onload='step1()'>\n" +
            "<img src='" + source + "' /></body></html>";
    }
    if(source) {
        var pwa = window.open('', '', 'height=800, width=800');
        pwa.document.write("<h1>Hello World!</h1><p>Have a nice day!</p>");
//        pwa.document.write(this.imagetoPrint(source));
        pwa.document.close();
      }
};
```

if change the IP to 'self' it is working.

Source is available as mention in image. click on 'stepover' it is showing error, blocking the browser print function.

how to check 'document.write' have permission ?? this might be causing the issue (not sure)

[image]

any idea how to cater this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Without the code in text format it makes harder to understand what could be missing. Could you share the code instead of screenshots?

Comment: You can't use `document.write` in a web component framework. By the time the script has loaded, the document is "closed" and cannot be written to. You'll need to use another method to do what you're trying to do, or perhaps just use a Visualforce page instead.

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to say you've made a Lightning Component using Aura?  While they are both Lightning Components, Lightning Web Components (aka LWCs) are totally separate from and are built differently from Aura Components.

Comment: Able to find answer of my question # 1  IP related,   Goto setup and search for 'CSP Trusted Sites'  add the 'New Trusted Site' and select either [connect-src or frame-src or img-src or style-src or font-src or media-src] and Save it.   Need to refresh browser multiple times OR clear cache.

Comment: @Sohail - I would make that an answer and not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Able to find answer of my question # 1 IP related:

Go to setup and search for 'CSP Trusted Sites'.

Click 'New Trusted Site' and select either [connect-src or frame-src or img-src or style-src or font-src or media-src] and Save it.

Need to refresh browser multiple times OR clear cache.

This solution worked for me.